# Referrer url in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, referrer

In angularjs I have a controller and depending on referrer url, I need to show a message, so can we do without writing any extra service, means is there any built in function in angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use $rootScope or define a service to save the old location